# what is hotkey to comment in "php designer 9"

Tags: php, hotkeys, phpdesigner

The problem is to comment the huge part of code in "php designer 9".

So what is hotkey to comment code in php designer 9?

Comment: What is you wans called block comment. Try to search for this, maybe that helps.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select text. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
To remove comments do the same.

Comment: Block comment isn't always the best option. Visually line comments are better to percept and they work without syntax highlighting. Also in some cases when debugging you want to comment a block and then remove comments from several lines. Also block comment brakes if you want to comment a part that already has a block comment.